# Add user to SQL Server in Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, ssms

I try to add user, I followed the steps here: [How to add users to SQL Server 2008 Managment Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364203/how-to-add-users-to-sql-server-2008-managment-studio)

All the steps was successful, but when I try to connect with the new user, I get an error - login failed for user..

Can someone help me?

Comment: Credentials error?
permissions to a database?
Windows login or SQL login?

Comment: "No process is on the other end of the pipe"-That what I get

Comment: you can take a look at the following post [Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175496(v=sql.105).aspx) or  [StackoverFlow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585069/sql-server-2008-connection-error-no-process-is-on-the-other-end-of-the-pipe)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using MSSQL as connection type as it's not the same as MySQL